# JavaScript не видит переменную

Tags: javascript

```
const go = new Go();
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
  fetch("build.wasm"), 
  go.importObject).then((result) => {
    mod = result.module;
    inst = result.instance;
  }
);
inst.initGrid(10, 10);
drawGrid();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть адекватная причина почему JS не видит эту переменную?

Comment: Пожалуйста, код текстом, а не картинками...

Comment: Во-первых, отлично видит и показывает её значение — undefined. Во-вторых, вы удивительно тактично обрезали правую часть кода. Давайте я погадаю на хрустальном шаре и угадаю что там — а там функция, которая не была вызвана, а так как она не была вызвана, то строчка `inst = resut.instance;` не была выполнена и значит значение переменной inst осталось undefined

Comment: И тот же хрустальный шар подсказывает мне, что это возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому коду который Вы предоставили, есть предположение что инициализация запаздывает из-за `асинхронного` метода, соответсвенно две нижние строки (или одну) нужно дописать в цепочку вызова.

```
const go = new Go();
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("build.wasm"), go.importObject)
.then((result) => {
   mod = result.module;
   inst = result.instance;  // присваиваем
})
.then(() => {
   inst.initGrid(10, 10);   // используем
   drawGrid();
});
```

Если не критично можно вообще обойтись одним `then` либо использовать `async/await`:

```
async function run(){
  const go = new Go();
  const result = await webAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("build.wasm"), go.importObject)
  mod = result.module;
  inst = result.instance;  // присваиваем
  inst.initGrid(10, 10);   // используем
  drawGrid();
}
```